# Google Cloud Kubernetes cluster can not connect to nodes or delete?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

I am using using google cloud Kubernetes service it was working until accidently i delete the service account of kubernetes service account. I have created the kubernetes service account. I can not connect to nodes delete or delete my cluster. Seems to that is permission issue. Also can not delete the computer engines. When i delete kubernetes cluster following error

> (1) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/projectid/global/firewalls/gke-kubeworld-383ec9cd-vms'
>
> (2) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/projectid/global/firewalls/gke-kubeworld-383ec9cd-ssh'
>
> (3) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/projectid/global/firewalls/gke-kubeworld-383ec9cd-all'
>
> (4) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.instanceGroupManagers.delete' permission for 'projects/projectid/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-kubeworld-default-pool-90dd280e-grp'
>
> (5.1) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.routes.list' permission for 'projects/projectid'
>
> (5.2) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/projectid'

how to configure or grant access to allow these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

These errors also depend on the overall situation of the project. Compute Engine service account manages lots of services, so upon deleting it, the errors come in different flavours.

When I get my SA deleted, I always do the same thing, as first step. Instead of going ahead and creating the service account manually, I enable an API that needs Compute Engine API, like Dataproc API. This should re-create Compute Engine service account, and in this case, as it is relevant, it also re-created Kubernetes Engine service account.

Once these accounts re-created, you should have different errors, as now the SA is there, but probably the token/credentials the cluster expects is the old one, but now you are passing a new token.

Can you confirm doing this you get the same errors or different? I'll edit the post once I get this info.

Answer (score 0):

Your service account lost roles after you re-created it.

First, use `gcloud auth login` and log into GCE account.

After the new service account is created, the role is required to be assigned to it.

In this case, the "roles/compute.admin" role is missed and needs to be reassigned.
I assume that you know the name of the service account you created.

It may help:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding  project-id \
    --member serviceAccount:service-account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role  roles/compute.admin
```

It is described at [AIM roles documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles).

EDITED: I found that is a another way to fix it:

```
gcloud service-management enable container.googleapis.com
```

Comment: You mean [`gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable)?